# Elasticsearch SQL filtering by @timestamp not working

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create an elastic query for a Kibana canvas entry and need to be able to filter by the @timestamp field.

This is the query I have tried that I thought would work from other answers to this problem:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT app) as counter FROM "snapshot*" where \"@timestamp\" >= '2020-11-01' and \"@timestamp\" <= '2021-11-01'
```

But I instead get this error back:

> [essql] > Couldn't parse Elasticsearch SQL query. You may need to add
> double quotes to names containing special characters. Check your query
> and try again. Error: [parsing_exception] line 1:76: extraneous input
> '' expecting {'(', 'ANALYZE', 'ANALYZED', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CATALOGS',
> 'COLUMNS', 'CONVERT', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME',
> 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'DAY', 'DEBUG', 'EXECUTABLE', 'EXISTS',
> 'EXPLAIN', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FIRST', 'FORMAT', 'FULL', 'FUNCTIONS',
> 'GRAPHVIZ', 'HOUR', 'INTERVAL', 'LAST', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'MAPPED',
> 'MATCH', 'MINUTE', 'MONTH', 'NOT', 'NULL', 'OPTIMIZED', 'PARSED',
> 'PHYSICAL', 'PLAN', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'QUERY', 'SCHEMAS', 'SECOND',
> 'SHOW', 'SYS', 'TABLES', 'TEXT', 'TRUE', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'VERIFY',
> 'YEAR', '{FN', '{D', '{T', '{TS', '{GUID', '+', '-', '*', '?', STRING,
> INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER,
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}

I'm not sure what else I can try as I've only seen the accepted answer to be to put @timestamp as "@timestamp" and it doesn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm using @timestamp from my elastic index. I saw from other answers for this similar problem use backslashes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try as `'timestamp'`, replacing `"timestamp"`, just single quotes.